# Nested directive not compiling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, selectize.js

I have a custom directive I have created that loads a template into a modal window. The modal window is a template itself and is able to run my custom directive without issues. That template that is loaded into the modal contains another directive which creates a select list using [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize). Here is my directive:

```
var dynamicTemplate = function($templateRequest, $compile) {

    return {
      restrict: "E",

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var modalOptions = JSON.parse(attrs.modalOptions);

        $templateRequest(modalOptions.Url).then(function(html) {

          $elem = $compile(html)(scope);   
          element.append($elem);
        });

      }
    }
  }
```

The HTML is getting loaded correctly, but the selectize directive is not initializing .

I have also tired this inside the `then` method:

```
element.html(html)
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

That gave me the same result.

The issue I am having is I am receiving this message after the compilation of the HTML:

```
TypeError: element.selectize is not a function
```

Here is [the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rx3KpxERZK34x2wSL7wq?p=preview) I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `angular.element` to use jQuery you have to include jQuery in page before angular loads.

Demo works fine once you change script order

[Updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WvxWvD0F0EX0dGqIUU5m?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

## First solution

You have to include jQuery.js before Angular.js in index.html. This *magic* makes angular.element to use jQuery.

[Solution 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/oMHkvuYKxSissJaZUoy0?p=info)

## Second solution

You may replace `element.selectize` with `$(element).selectize` in angular-selectize.js on line 97. This makes angular-selectize script to use jQuery's selector instead of angular's.

[Solution 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9ePO2ywDlQsAtSHgi5E?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery in the page before Angular loads. Then angular.element will use jQuery.